# ContextMenuButtonItem! How to change styles of ContextMenuButtonItem flutter. Copy/paste buttons toolbar flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield, toolbar, copy-paste

How can i change a styles for ContextMenuButtonItem
I don't want to redo the entire functionality in order to change the 2 styles for the Android button.
Maybe there is a change of styles for these buttons in Themedata?

```
 TextField(

    contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
     
      final value = editableTextState.textEditingValue;
      final List<ContextMenuButtonItem> buttonItems = [
        ContextMenuButtonItem(
          onPressed: () {},
          type: ContextMenuButtonType.custom,
        )
      ];

      return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
          buttonItems: buttonItems, anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors);
    },
)
```

I made a separate class where I made my own widgets. But I can't connect List  and List

```
class _MyContextMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyContextMenu({
    required this.anchor,
    required this.children,
    required this.contextMenuButtonItems,
  });

  final Offset anchor;
  final List<Widget> children;
  final List<ContextMenuButtonItem> contextMenuButtonItems;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    contextMenuButtonItems.insert(0, Container() as ContextMenuButtonItem);
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          height: 34,
          top: anchor.dy + 38,
          left: anchor.dx - 24,
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2)),
            child: Center(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  ...children,
                  ...contextMenuButtonItems.map((item) => YourWidget(item)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```